# Mongoid - Array assignment

Tags: mongoid

I'm seeing some strange behaviour in Mongoid 2.3.4

```
 class Student
   has_and_belongs_to_many: teachers
 end

 class Teacher
   has_and_belongs_to_many: students
 end
```

Now in IRB

```
s = Student.first
s.teachers
=> []

s.teacher_ids = [Teacher.first.id, Teacher.last.id]
s.teacher_ids
=> [[BSON::ObjectId4f7c3300913417162c000008, BSON::ObjectId4f7c333b913417162c00000d]]
```

Not sure why this array is nested like that. I expected

```
[BSON::ObjectId4f7c3300913417162c000008, BSON::ObjectId4f7c333b913417162c00000d]
```

This breaks multi select fields in Rails, where the mass assignments of ids would happen like shown in IRB.

Comment: Why don't you upgrade to a newer version of mongoid?

Comment: Ok, I'll check to see if that behavior is corrected in newer versions. Do you see it working correctly in a newer version ?

Comment: I have many such fields in my views and they work perfectly fine for me. I had it working in 2.2.2 and also after the switch to 2.4.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may have to do with the fact that you're attempting to set the `teachers_ids` attribute to an array of `Teacher` objects.

You could try these as alternatives:

```
s.teachers = [Teacher.first, Teacher.last]
```

or

```
s.teachers << Teacher.first
s.teachers << Teacher.last
```

**Update:**

I've just run a little test and can confirm that your method of assignment works fine in Mongoid 2.4.6 (which is just what I happened to have installed) and 2.4.8.

If for some reason you can't upgrade to Mongoid 2.4, you could also try passing the IDs in as `String` objects instead of as `ObjectId`, which is how it would be handled if this was being passed in through POST parameters.

```
s.teacher_ids = [Teacher.first.id.to_s, Teacher.last.id.to_s]
```

Comment: That usage works. My usage simulates the way Rails would handle the POST params -  mass assign the array of ids. For example, if the teacher is being chosen from a multi select list, the post params would have a list of teacher ids, like [1,2,3] which would then be mass assigned to the student, ie. student.teacher_ids = [1,2,3]

Comment: I've updated my answer, seems like all the different assignment methods work fine in Mongoid 2.4.x